Error in a basic contract test with Solidity and Mocha
I am new at Solidity and this is my first contract.
I am encountering the following error:
PS D:\Blockchain\first> npm run test

> firstchain@1.0.0 test
> mocha

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module './uws_win32_ia32_108.node'
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.




  Inbox
eth_accounts
eth_getBlockByNumber
eth_blockNumber
eth_sendTransaction

  Transaction: 0x56f85dce06cd0ed3f8d14836978958986275450b52f406061838fb0091e35483
  Contract created: 0x35f2d1acd0ce8675026d43aa77b506a31b8bce62
  Gas usage: 2000000
  Block number: 1
  Block time: Tue Jul 23 2024 01:06:51 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
  Runtime error: invalid opcode

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_blockNumber
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


  0 passing (195ms)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     Web3ContractError: code couldn't be stored
      at Object.transactionResolver (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\commonjs\contract.js:882:27)
      at SendTxHelper.<anonymous> (node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:159:84)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at D:\Blockchain\firstChain\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:8:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:4:12)
      at SendTxHelper.handleResolve (node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\send_tx_helper.js:157:16)
      at D:\Blockchain\firstChain\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:394:48
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58)


The contract file (Inbox.sol) is following:
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory initialMessage) {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
    return message;
    }

}

The compile.js file is following:
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Inbox.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, "utf8");

//console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));

// Define input structure for solc.compile
const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "Inbox.sol": {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

// Compile the contract
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const contracts = output.contracts["Inbox.sol"];
//console.log(contracts.Inbox.evm.bytecode.object);
module.exports = {
  interface: JSON.stringify(contracts.Inbox.abi),
  bytecode: contracts.Inbox.evm.bytecode.object,
};


and the Inbox.test.sol file is the following:
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache");
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");

let accounts;
let inbox;
beforeEach(async () => {
  //Get a list of all accounts
  //   web3.eth.getAccounts().then((fetchedAccounts) => {
  //     console.log(fetchedAccounts);
  //   });

  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  //Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ["hi"] })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "2000000" });
});

describe("Inbox", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {
    assert.ok(inbox.options.address);
  });
});


I ran these commands in terminal:
npm init
npm install --save solc mocha web3 ganache
I guess there is an issue with ganache but I am not sure. npm audit fix has been tried already. Also, issues with gas limit were thrown before the last adjustment in .send function. Thanks...

you might need to upgrade the node version

Try to add "0x0" in front of bytecode, so the line should be:
.deploy({ data: "0x0" + bytecode, arguments: ["hi"] })

Give it a try and let me know.
